# ReadFile doesn't work asynchronously on Win7 and Win2k8

Tags: winapi, windows-7, asynchronous

According to MSDN, `ReadFile` can read data 2 different ways: synchronously and asynchronously.
I need the second one. The folowing code demonstrates usage with `OVERLAPPED` struct:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void Read()
{
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileA("c:\\1.avi", GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);
    if ( hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
    {
        printf("Failed to open the file\n");
        return;
    }

    int dataSize = 256 * 1024 * 1024;
    char* data = (char*)malloc(dataSize);
    memset(data, 0xFF, dataSize);

    OVERLAPPED overlapped;
    memset(&overlapped, 0, sizeof(overlapped));

    printf("reading: %d\n", time(NULL));
    BOOL result = ReadFile(hFile, data, dataSize, NULL, &overlapped);
    printf("sent: %d\n", time(NULL));


    DWORD bytesRead;
    result = GetOverlappedResult(hFile, &overlapped, &bytesRead, TRUE); // wait until completion - returns immediately
    printf("done: %d\n", time(NULL));

    CloseHandle(hFile);
}



int main()
{
        Read();
}
```

On Windows XP output is: 
reading: 1296651896
sent: 1296651896
done: 1296651899

It means that `ReadFile` didn't block and returned imediatly at the same second, whereas reading process continued for 3 seconds. It is normal async reading.

But on windows 7 and windows 2008 I get following results:
reading: 1296661205
sent: 1296661209
done: 1296661209.
It is a behavior of sync reading.

MSDN says that async `ReadFile` sometimes can behave as sync (when the file is compressed or encrypted for example). But the return value in this situation should be TRUE and `GetLastError()` == NO_ERROR.
On Windows 7 I get FALSE and `GetLastError()` == ERROR_IO_PENDING. So WinApi tells me that it is an async call, but when I look at the test I see that it is not!

I'm not the only one who found this "bug": read the comment on ReadFile MSDN page.

So what's the solution? Does anybody know? It is been 14 months after Denis found this strange behavior.

Comment: The file I/O subsystem was dramatically changed for Win7.  This isn't otherwise a problem, you get a proper read when you follow the contract.

Comment: where can i read documentation? what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Last year, I was investigating doing async WriteFile calls and hit the same issue you did.  The WriteFile call would block and return PENDING.  Subsequent waits for the IO result would return immediately as well.  The only solution was to CreateThread or QueueUserWorkItem. (Or live with the perf hit on the main thread). I played around with the BUFFERING flags as suggested below.  No dice.

Comment: I too tried to find a solution for this issue. Ended up using a thread as well.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know the size of the "c:\1.avi" file but the size of the buffer you give to Windows (256M!) is probably big enough to hold the file. So windows decides to read the whole file and put it in the buffer the way it likes. You don't say to windows "I want async", you say "I know how to handle async".

Just change the buffer size say 1024, and your program will behave exactly the same, but read only 1024 bytes (and return ERROR_IO_PENDING as well).

In general, you do asynchronous because you want to do something else during the operation. Look at the sample here: [Testing for the End of a File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365690%28VS.85%29.aspx), as it demonstrate an async ReadFile. If you change the sample's buffer and set it to a big value, it should  behave exactly like yours.

PS: I suggest you don't rely on time samples to check things, use return codes and events

Comment: 1.avi's size is 600 MB. Windows reads only part of the file. Reading 256 MB from disk takes few seconds. I think that async ReadFile should take less that 1 second. But timings say that ReadFile blocks and reads that 256 MB while suspending my thread!

Comment: all i want from ReadFile is to read this 256 mb without suspending my thread for so long!

Comment: @f0b0s - Again, async ReadFile does not mean "dear Windows, please return now and do your work later", it just means "I can handle async IO operations". There is no notion of maximum time taken or maximum number of bytes read between each call, except of course by the size of the buffer you pass. If all you care is to read 256M and not be blocked, you could use another thread (like thread pool's QueueUserWorkItem function) to do it.

Comment: It is vey bad if so. In linux async means -- don't block, please and read in OS thread. I agree with you that it is not a bug of windows but a strange behavior. But you should understand my position: I need non-blocking ReadFile  not because I can handle it but I need this behavior to make my database work fast.

Comment: You can use `ReadFileEx` for forceful async

Answer (score 1):

This probably has something to do with caching.  Try to open the file non-cached (`FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`)

**EDIT**

This is actually documented in the MSDN documentation for [ReadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365467%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> Note  If a file or device is opened
>   for asynchronous I/O, subsequent calls
>   to functions such as ReadFile using
>   that handle generally return
>   immediately, but can also behave
>   synchronously with respect to blocked
>   execution. For more information see
>   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/156932.

Comment: reading non-cached file is really unpleasant with all its alignment rules

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/10/08/10073039.aspx), I would suspect that it should return TRUE in your case. But it may also be that the completion modes default settings are different on Win7/Win2k8.
Try setting a different mode with [SetFileCompletionNotificationModes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365538%28VS.85%29.aspx)().

Comment: no, it returns false! i double-checked that. but i'll trye changing settings, thanx!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use an event as @Simon Mourier suggested ?.  I know that the documentation says that the event is not required, but if you see the example in links provided by @Simon Mourier, it is using an event for asynchronous read.

Comment: Yes, i did. The code was just to show the idea of my question. ReadFile returns with ERROR_IO_PENDING and WaitForSingleObject returns immediatly.

Answer (score 1):

Windows7/Server2008 have different behavior to resolve a race condition that can occurn in GetOverlappedResultEx.  When you compile for these OS's Windows detects this and uses different behavior.  I find this wicked confusing.

Here is a link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371711(VS.85).aspx

I'm sure you've read this many times in the past, but some of the text has changed since Win7 - esp the hEvent field in the OVERLAPPED struct, 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684342(v=VS.85).aspx

> Functions such as
>   GetOverlappedResult and the
>   synchronization wait functions reset
>   auto-reset events to the nonsignaled
>   state. **Therefore, you should use a
>   manual reset event**; *if you use an
>   auto-reset event, your application can
>   stop responding if you wait for the
>   operation to complete* and then call
>   GetOverlappedResult with the bWait
>   parameter set to TRUE.

could you do an experiment - please allocate a manual reset event in your OVERLAPPED struct instead of a auto reset event?  (I dont see the allocation in your snippit - dont forget to create the event and to set 'hEvent' after zeroing the struct)

Comment: I'mcurrently reading Richter's book and my OVERLAPPED-based class uses manual-reset event (just because I need this event only one time: when operation finishes). Every new async overation gets new OVERLAPPED structure with new event.

Comment: I tried with manual event and GetOverlappedResult -- nope, writing is async and reading is sync