# ReadFileEx/WriteFileEx no need to lpCompletionRoutine and use of GetOverlappedResult?

Tags: c, winapi, asynchronous

I want to use **ReadFileEx**/**WriteFileEx** functions for asynchronous I/O on Serial Ports, and I do not need to **lpCompletionRoutine** parameter for APC.

1- Could the lpCompletionRoutine parameter be set to **NULL** ?

2- Could I use **GetOverlappedResult** with **bWait** parameter set to **TRUE** to block until **ReadFileEx**/**WriteFileEx** completes rather than using **WaitForSingleObjectEx**, because I already set the communication timeouts with **SetCommTimeouts** !!!???

Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: @RbMm, **ReadFile** does not guarantee to be always asynchronous, sometimes when configured to be asynchronous, it reads synchronously, and this could be a problem.  Because of that I have switched to **ReadFileEx**

Comment: you mistake. you completely not understand windows asynchronous io/ and absolute no different in `ReadFile` and `ReadFileEx` when you not use `lpCompletionRoutine` - this is 100%. asynchronous or synchronous io depended from how you open file only .at all - if you want this kind of code - simply open file as **synchronous** - for what you open it for asynchronous I/O ??

Comment: for driver which handle your file in most case no different in which mode you open file. i/o subsystem in **kernel** if file open for synchronous i/o and driver return pending status - begin wait in place when operation complete. if file open for asynchronous i/o - i/o subsystem just return control for you, even if pending returned. and what you plain to do on pending ? simply wait for operation complete. in this case let i/o subsystem do this. for what do the same yourself ?

Comment: @RbMm, I don't think so. For now I have spent a week to finally figure out that **ReadFile** does not guarantee to be asynchronous if it has configured to be.  read this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/156932/asynchronous-disk-i-o-appears-as-synchronous-on-windows  and this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110923-00/?p=9563

Comment: again you mistake. i have huge knowledge in this topic. `ReadFile` and `ReadFileEx` is very twin shell over `ZwReadFile` it simply call it. `ReadFile` also **wait** if you got status pending from `ZwReadFile` and **lpOverlapped == 0**. but you and **want** wait.

Comment: the link which you post - absolute not related to which function you use `ReadFile` or `ReadFileEx` or `ZwReadFile` !!! this is **file driver** related. your problem - bad understand windows internals (i/o subsystem)

Comment: @RbMm what about this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878868/readfile-doesnt-work-asynchronously-on-win7-and-win2k8

Comment: "ReadFile does not guarantee" - **mistake**. ReadFile call `ZwReadFile` then if pending returned **and** `lpOverlapped == 0` - it call `WaitOnSingleObject(hFile, INFINITE)` (but you and want this really , if i correct understand you) otherwise control returned to you just. again - i **expert** in this topic and know all about this

Comment: all what you post related **NOT** to user mode ReadFile or ReadFileEx or ZwReadFile. this related to how kernel mode file system driver work

Comment: and can you explain what you actually want ? from your question - you want **synchronous** i/o. so the best for this case - open file in **synchronous** mode and use `ReadFile`. if you however open it in asynchronous mode - any way call `ReadFile` but you **must** set overlapped to non 0 - *If hFile was opened with FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, the lpOverlapped parameter must not be NULL* and then you want wait when operation complete . if you want really asynchronous behavior - you need absolute another code

Comment: The problem is I don't know how many bytes to read, for this case I set a timeout, so that the **ReadFileEx** wont block forever, and will wait for some bytes as response. And If I do synchronous read with **ReadFile**, this last one will read **0 bytes** and return if there are no ones to read.

Comment: `I don't know how many bytes to read` - but you need set some buffer to where read and pass *nNumberOfBytesToRead* to both functions. the comm timeout is set on file **handle** and have effect for **all** read file functions (with and without `Ex` or for `Zw`). and you can not do `do synchronous read with ReadFile` if file opened with `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` !! show your code

Comment: again - are you understand that in your case( no *lpCompletionRoutine* ) **no different** between **ReadFileEx** and **ReadFile** ? the best of course use *ZwReadFile* it can return to you `STATUS_TIMEOUT` if you use it with synchronous handle. while ReadFile[Ex] **lost** this status

Comment: it is a long code library : https://github.com/tomay3000/libserialport

Comment: try understand `ReadFile` and `ReadFileEx` is **small** shell over [`ZwReadFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567072(v=vs.85).aspx) - extra parameter for `Ex` version - *lpCompletionRoutine* is used as to *ApcRoutine* but you **not use** this parameter !! and after `ZwReadFile` return `ReadFileEx` is just and unconditeonally return control for you. the `ReadFile` if `ZwReadFile` return `STATUS_PENDING` and **lpOverlapped is NULL** - call *WaitForSingleObject* on *hFile* - this is all different.

Comment: the com-timeout is have effect for how **driver** process you read request (cancel it by timeout). so absolute no different +/- `Ex` version you use.

Comment: i don`t know linux at all. if write code only for windows, better use absolute another code for asynchronous i/o. and you incorrect use it now..

Comment: you need determinate for yourself:
1) are you want use synchronous (so just wait after read until operation not complete) or asyncronous(call and forget - **callback** will be executed when io finished) i/o ?
2) are you want most effective, native for windows code or it must be maximum cross platform ?
3) for `ReadFile` and `ReadFileEx` you mistake. this is only **thin shell** over `ZwReadFile`. `Ex` version have one extra parameter which you not use. version without `Ex` can conditionally wait for operation complete (**only** if no overlapped in input)

Comment: and i **mistake** in first comment.   the *lpCompletionRoutine* parameter **must be not** NULL  or will be crash at 0 address **if** you will be wait in alertable state after success *ReadFileEx*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must provide a valid completion routine when calling `ReadFileEx` since if you provide an invalid address your program will crash as soon as the APC is processed.  (Or, if you do not process APCs, the presence of too many queued I/O completions is likely to eventually cause problems.  Apart from anything else, you can't legally reuse the I/O buffer until the APC has been called.)

In any case, the completion routine is the only way for you tell that the I/O is complete.  As described in the documentation, the `ReadFileEx` function ignores the `OVERLAPPED` structure's `hEvent` member.  Of course, you could always put an event object in `hEvent` anyway and point `ReadFileEx` to a completion routine that does nothing but set the event.

**However,** your original premise (that using `ReadFileEx` will avoid the possibility of the read taking place synchronously) is incorrect.  It is true that in certain cases Windows will complete a nominally asynchronous I/O operation synchronously, but this is due to limitations in the I/O drivers and affects both `ReadFile` *and* `ReadFileEx` in exactly the same way.

It isn't clear to me from what little you've said in the comments what your actual scenario is, or what problem you're experiencing that you believe to be due to unexpectedly synchronous I/O.  Serial port drivers are perhaps more likely than most to exhibit that behaviour, so it is certainly plausible that this is the cause of your problem, but you will need to find another solution.  You might use `SetCommMask` to detect whether input is available, for example, and set the timeouts to make the I/O non-blocking, this would make the I/O semantics similar to those provided by Linux.

If you are unsure how to proceed, I recommend you ask another question, including details of what you are trying to achieve and what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: `In any case, the completion routine is the only way for you tell that the I/O is complete` - this not exactly. even if no event, completion routine and *IOCP* on file - i/o manager [set](https://github.com/bigzz/WRK/blob/master/base/ntos/io/iomgr/internal.c#L1377) embedded in file object [*Event*](https://github.com/bigzz/WRK/blob/master/base/ntos/io/iomgr/internal.c#L1413). thereby this we can wait on `hFile` or use `GetOverlappedResult` for wait when i/o complete.

Comment: @RbMm, I'd overlooked that option.  I agree that will work, but it isn't recommended.  I believe the main reason is that it won't work properly if there are multiple I/O operations outstanding on the same handle, which is a common scenario when using asynchronous I/O.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, You are right, **ReadFile** and **ReadFileEx** are both affected. It turns out that it is a serial port device driver issue, because I have tried two different phone modems connected through USB. **Sony Ericsson phone modem** which works without problems, and **LG phone modem** which is not considering timeouts at all, and its **ReadFile** function returns immediately with 0 bytes read, as if it is working synchronously.  I should drop using **SetCommTimeouts** and start seeking for alternatives.

Comment: Returning immediately with 0 bytes read is the correct behaviour if no data is waiting and the port is set to non-blocking.  You should consider posting another question, with [mcve] code.

Answer (score 3):

the *formal* answers:

> Could the lpCompletionRoutine parameter be set to NULL ?

**no**. this parameter is mandatory and can not be NULL. *lpCompletionRoutine* will be called if you will be wait in **alertable** state after successful call `ReadFileEx`. so if you pass NULL - this address and will be called. however this bug you can and not catch if you will be never wait in **alertable** state. but if you than add this kind of code, or system itself will be wait in this state indirectly (say you call some api or some changed in new windows version) - you suddenly got crash - very far from call `ReadFileEx` in absolute unrelated code - and will be long and hard research why this happens.

> Could I use GetOverlappedResult with bWait parameter set to TRUE to
>   block until ReadFileEx/WriteFileEx completes rather than using
>   WaitForSingleObjectEx

**yes, you can do this** (if *hEvent* from [`OVERLAPPED`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684342(v=vs.85).aspx) `== 0`). `GetOverlappedResult` if operation still not complete, when you call `GetOverlappedResult` (*it determinate this by compare `Internal` member of [`OVERLAPPED`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684342(v=vs.85).aspx) with `STATUS_PENDING`*) - function call `WaitForSingleObject[Ex]` on *hEvent* from [`OVERLAPPED`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684342(v=vs.85).aspx) **if it not NULL** otherwise it will be wait on *hFile*.

but from [`ReadFileEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365468(v=vs.85).aspx) :

> The ReadFileEx function ignores the OVERLAPPED structure's hEvent
>   member.

this mean it not pass it to [`ZwReadFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567072(v=vs.85).aspx) (as second parameter *Event*), and kernel as result not set this event when i/o finished. but while `ReadFileEx` ignore *hEvent* member, the `GetOverlappedResult` not ignore it and use, if it not NULL. so it must be NULL. in this case `GetOverlappedResult` will be work(wait) with your *hFile* and all will be ok (i/o subsystem set internal event in [`FILE_OBJECT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545834(v=vs.85).aspx) when operation finished)

---

what is different between [`ReadFileEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365468(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`ReadFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467(v=vs.85).aspx) ? both functions is thin shell over [`ZwReadFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567072(v=vs.85).aspx) - *which is you can call direct both from user - it much more power* . how you can see [`ZwReadFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567072(v=vs.85).aspx) have more parameters compare ReadFile[Ex]. how this parameters is passed from `ReadFile[Ex]` to `ZwReadFile` ?

1. the `ReadFile` pass `hEvent` from `OVERLAPPED` to `ZwReadFile`
   (*`Event [in, optional]`* ) but `ReadFile[Ex]` always pass 0 in place
   *`Event`* to `ZwReadFile`
2. *`ApcRoutine [in, optional]`* - obviously `ReadFile` pass 0 here, but `ReadFileEx` passed here some internal routine
   `BaseIoCompletion[Simply]` (always, even if your
   *lpCompletionRoutine* is 0). this routine convert *`NTSTATUS`* code from [`PIO_STATUS_BLOCK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550671(v=vs.85).aspx) (*second parameter*) to win32 error (by
   call [`RtlNtStatusToDosError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680600(v=vs.85).aspx)). and than call your
   *lpCompletionRoutine* (*it take this from `ApcContext`* - first parameter). if it 0 - so 0 and will be called. with well known
   result.
3. important note - if *IOCP* port is bind to your file(by calling
   [`BindIoCompletionCallback`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363484(v=vs.85).aspx), [`CreateThreadpoolIo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682464(v=vs.85).aspx),
   [`CreateIoCompletionPort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363862(v=vs.85).aspx) or by setting
   [`FileCompletionInformation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff728840(v=vs.85).aspx)  - you can not use `ApcRoutine`
   (not 0) - this is mutually exclusive methods for I/O completion. and
   you got `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER` from i/o subsystem
4. *`ApcContext [in, optional]`* - the `ReadFile` pass pointer to your
   *lpOverlapped* here. thereby you can get it (pointer) back in [`FileIOCompletionRoutine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364052(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`IoCompletionCallback`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684124(v=vs.85).aspx), or
   by direct call `ZwRemoveIoCompletion`

   `ReadFileEx` pass here your *lpCompletionRoutine*. thereby that
   `BaseIoCompletion[Simply]` stub get it back in as *ApcContext* and
   use to call your original *lpCompletionRoutine* (even if it 0)
5. *`IoStatusBlock`* `ReadFileEx` here passed pointer to your *lpOverlapped* **unconditionally**. `ReadFile` pass your *lpOverlapped* if it not 0. otherwise it allocate it in stack, as local variable
   and use this pointer. from this follows that `ReadFile` in this case
   (*lpOverlapped==0*) can not return until operation not finished -
   because [`IO_STATUS_BLOCK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550671(v=vs.85).aspx) must be valid while i/o not complete,
   but local variable become not valid after function return.
6. what passed to *`Buffer [out]`* and *`Length [in]`* think obviously
7. *`ByteOffset [in, optional]`* - if *lpOverlapped* not 0, local variable `LARGE_INTEGER ByteOffset` allocated (ok, it of course
   declared (so allocated) always, simply i mean that it *used* in this
   case) and initialized from *Offset* and *OffsetHigh* members of
   overlapped. if *lpOverlapped* is 0 (in case `ReadFile`) the NULL
   pointer passed as *`ByteOffset`*
8. important note. if file open in asynchronous mode (with the
    `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` flag if we use [`CreateFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) or with
    `WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` if we use [`WSASocket`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742212(v=vs.85).aspx)( or
    [`socket`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740506(v=vs.85).aspx)) or if we **not use** `FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT`
    and `FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_ALERT` flags in [`ZwCreateFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566424(v=vs.85).aspx) or
    [`ZwOpenFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567011(v=vs.85).aspx) ) the *`ByteOffset`* is **mandatory** parameter
    (except named pipe and mail slot file types). if it will be 0 - i/o
    subsystem return to as `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER`. as result
    *lpOverlapped* parameter must not be NULL - because (7). this is said in documentation from `ReadFile`:

   > If hFile is opened with FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, the lpOverlapped
   >   parameter must not be NULL. It must point to a valid OVERLAPPED
   >   structure.
9. *`Key [in, optional]`* - always 0, we not control this when call `ReadFile[Ex]`. look [`ZwLockFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566474(v=vs.85).aspx) *Key* parameter if you want
   understand this parameter. win32 shell [`LockFileEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365203(v=vs.85).aspx) is
   restricted.

after `ZwReadFile` is called and returned *NTSTATUS status* -

- `ReadFileEx` check for [`NT_ERROR(status)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565436(v=vs.85).aspx) and if this true
  convert and set win32 error and return *FALSE* otherwise it return
  *TRUE*. so say for `STATUS_PENDING` this function return `TRUE`. more interesting that for [`NT_WARNING(status)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565436(v=vs.85).aspx) (which is really
  error status) it also return `TRUE`. however i never view case when
  `ZwReadFile` return this range of status, but some custom driver of
  course can do that
- `ReadFile` must have special case for `STATUS_PENDING` when
  *lpOverlapped* is 0 how i explain in (5). so it called `ZwWaitForSingleObject(hFile..)` for wait until operation complete
  and than use status from `IO_STATUS_BLOCK`

  in case *lpOverlapped* not NULL - `ReadFile` not wait itself. it
  convert status to win32 error if not [`NT_SUCCESS(status)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565436(v=vs.85).aspx) and
  return `FALSE` . also it check for `STATUS_PENDING` and return
  `FALSE` in this case also (and set last error to `ERROR_IO_PENDING`
  ). otherwise it return `TRUE`. and special case exist for error status - `STATUS_END_OF_FILE`:

  > When a synchronous read operation reaches the end of a file, ReadFile
  >   returns TRUE and sets *lpNumberOfBytesRead to zero.
  >   *but why this special case ?! why not convert it to `ERROR_HANDLE_EOF` and return `FALSE` ?*

note that in case with serial file handle, when we call [`SetCommTimeouts`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363437(v=vs.85).aspx) - serial driver, if timeout expired - cancel read operation and return `STATUS_TIMEOUT` as final status. but this is not error status. as result both `ReadFile` and `ReadFileEx` **lost** this status. it return `TRUE` and not set `ERROR_TIMEOUT` as last error or not called your `FileIOCompletionRoutine` with this code. but with `NOERROR` code. so will be not native determinate that your read operation ended by timeout if use win32 api. need check bytes read. however if use `ZwReadFile` - no any problem - we got `STATUS_TIMEOUT` in `IO_STATUS_BLOCK` as is. and will be know exactly that timeout was.

what is conclusion from this ? main read operation will be in kernel mode, in driver code. and are it will be synchronous or synchronous *in driver* - we almost not control. driver can ignore `FO_SYNCHRONOUS_IO` flag in `FILE_OBJECT`. however most drivers process i/o operations (including read) asynchronous, even if you open file in synchronous mode. and return `STATUS_PENDING`. the i/o subsystem already check for this special status and *wait* if pending returned **and** you open file in synchronous mode. and all this inside `ZwReadFile` call. in kernel. so no different between `ReadFile` and `ReadFileEx` at this point. different only **after** `ZwReadFile` return - `ReadFileEx` just return to you. when `ReadFile` will be wait if pending returned and *lpOverlapped* is 0. but we full control this behavior by *lpOverlapped* - set it to pointer to a valid OVERLAPPED structure - and `ReadFile` will be never wait.

so synchronous or asynchronous behavior of read determinate not by select `ReadFile` or `ReadFileEx` but in which mode (with which flags) you open file. (driver how i say can sometime ignore asynchronous handle and process i/o synchronously). and by  *lpOverlapped* (0 or not 0) in case `ReadFile` (but here all exactly determinated)

---

the call [`SetCommTimeouts`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363437(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_TIMEOUTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544126(v=vs.85).aspx) (`SetCommTimeouts` simply send this ioctl to driver) have effect for file. and after this absolute no different - use you `ReadFile` or `ReadFileEx` - both give you the same result in case timeout.

---

and last - if you want just wait for operation complete after pending returned - this is synchronous I/O by fact. in this case you not need open file in asynchronous mode - this is senseless with this kind of code. simply open as synchronous and use `ReadFile`